# not able to store a csv file data into an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, csv

Not able to store the data in an array & plot the array data on scatterplot

```
with open('Infosys.csv','r') as csv_file :
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
print(csv_reader)
next(csv_reader)
for line in csv_reader :
    x[i] = line[2]
    print(x)
    i=i+1



 #X = array.array('i',x)
with open('Infosys.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
     csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
     print(csv_reader)
     next(csv_reader)
     for p in csv_reader :
        y = p[5]
        print(y)

plt.scatter(x,y,label='pt.',color='red')
```

Comment: You should post a sample of your csv file here (say top 5 rows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `list` of (x, y) tuples from the CSV data using a list comprehension. Then use `zip` to separate the tuples into x an y values and pass to `plt.scatter()`:

```
with open('Infosys.csv','r') as csv_file :
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    next(csv_reader)
    data = [(row[2], row[5]) for row in csv_reader]

    plt.scatter(*zip(*data), label='pt.', color='red')
```

This requires a only single pass over the file.